# GCC: Allow overloaded functions in C99

Tags: c, gcc, c99, overloading

I write code in C99 and compile via GCC. I would like to use function overloading for stylistic reasons (otherwise I would have to do name mangling by myself).

I have read [Is there a reason that C99 doesn't support function overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314613/is-there-a-reason-that-c99-doesnt-support-function-overloading) however, I still wonder whether it can be enabled in GCC.

Can you help me at this point?

Comment: A simple workaround is to use C++ instead of C. Also, overloading needs name decoration, which is present in C++ but not in C. So C++ is in fact your key.

Comment: What is `CGG` ? If you want high level language features such as function overloading then you should probably consider a more appropriate language, such as C++.

Comment: The world, and our machines, are ready for a C version that doesn't need a linker!   Progress.  Definitely puts it ahead of the C++ guys.

Comment: I'm assuming `CGG` is a typo for `GCC`?

Comment: Table of function pointers. Bang. Done.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506988/function-overloading-in-c-using-gcc-compiler-warnings It's ugly, but it is possible.

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no function overloading in C99, not even in silly GCC extensions. C11 adds `_Generic`, but even then you still have to mangle names yourself.

```
void foo_int(int x);
void foo_double(double x);

#define foo(arg) _Generic((arg), int: foo_int, double: foo_double)(arg)
```

Whether that's better or worse, well. It's C.

Comment: Comes closest to the feature I am looking for.

Comment: This is not true. Function overloading is possible with "silly" GCC extensions. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506988/function-overloading-in-c-compiler-warnings

Comment: The solution I linked works in C99. You stated that it is impossible in C99.

Comment: Good thing someone watches out for those poor C99 users in A.D. 2016!!

Comment: Someone has to. ;)  Besides, that is what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 4):

In C macros may partially replace function overloading of other languages. As Cat Plus Plus indicates in her answer C11 has the additional construct `_Generic` to program type generic macros.

With C99 you already have possibilities to program macros that are in some sense type generic. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__default__arguments.html) has facilities that ease the use of that, e.g to call such a macro with a different number of parameters. To distinguish which function to call according to a specific parameter `A` you could then use something like `(sizeof(A) == sizeof(float) ? sqrtf(A) : sqrt(A))`.

Gcc has extensions that allow to program such things even more comfortably, namely block expressions with `({ any code here })` and `typeof` to declare auxiliary variables of the same type as a macro parameter.

Comment: Why do you think @CatPlusPlus is a `she`?

Comment: Why should I suppose that it is a he? (But maybe I am too much influenced by my mother tongue where "cat" is of feminine gender.)

Comment: @JensGustedt hey, in French, "cat" is of masculine gender. if you say it in the feminine form, you could say something not very polite...

Answer (score 3):

LLVM Clang3.3 has introduced function overloading. In fact, function overloading might not so easy as you expect. It involves such problems as function-call convention and ABI(Application Binary Interface). When you mix your C code with assembly language, those problems may occur.
When you work with assembly procedures, the names of the exported procedures should not be overloaded.

In LLVM Clang, you can do this with attribute (overloadable):

```
static void __attribute__((overloadable)) MyFunc(float x)
{
    puts("This is a float function");
}

static int __attribute__((overloadable)) MyFunc(int x)
{
    puts("This is an integer function");
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct core * __must_check getAnyCore(unsigned long v,...) {
    va_list ap;
    struct core *c = NULL;
    va_start(ap, v);
    switch (v) {
        case sizeof(struct device):
            c = (va_arg(ap, struct device *))->c;
            break;
        case sizeof(struct driver):
            c = (va_arg(ap, struct driver *))->c;
            break;
        default:
            c = NULL;
            break;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return c;
}

#define getCore(obj) getAnyCore(sizeof(*obj),obj)
```

I implemented the overloading of C in this way, but the limitation is that the sizes of 'struct device' and 'struct driver' are inconsistent.