# Function overloading in C using GCC - compiler warnings

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings, c99, overloading

I am attempting to implement function overloading in **C**, and I am very close.  I am using C99 so the `_Generic` keyword introduced in C11 is not available to me.  I have developed some working code, but when I compile it I get a couple warnings.

Working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(x)                                                                        \
__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int   ), print_int(x)   , \
__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]), print_string(x), \
(void)0))


void print_int(int i) {
    printf("int: %d\n", i);
}

void print_string(char* s) {
    printf("char*: %s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    print(1);
    print("this");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling creates the following warnings:

```
gcc overload.c -o main
overload.c: In function 'main':
overload.c:19: warning: passing argument 1 of 'print_string' makes pointer from integer without a cast
overload.c:20: warning: passing argument 1 of 'print_int' makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

For a little more debugging information, here is what the main function looks like after the preprocessor does its work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(1), int ), print_int(1) , __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(1), char[]), print_string(1), (void)0));
 __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof("this"), int ), print_int("this") , __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof("this"), char[]), print_string("this"), (void)0));

 return 0;
}
```

How can I make the compilation warnings go away and still have working code?

Comment: I believe its the calls to `print_string(1)` and `print_int("this")` that are causing the warnings, but these calls should never happen since the types won't match.

Comment: Instead of choosing `print_int(x)` or `print_string(x)`, what if you choose `print_int` or `print_string` and apply the chosen function (pointer) to x?

Comment: @user2357112, How would I go about doing that?  I'm not very good with function pointers.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer, since it was too messy for a comment. See if it works; if it doesn't, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, this should work:

```
#define print(x)                                                                      \
(__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int   ), print_int   , \
 __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]), print_string, \
(void)0))(x))
```

It chooses either `print_int` or `print_string`, then applies the chosen function to `x`.

Comment: That's good, it will trigger a compiler error when the specified type isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

The [GNU page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) on the build-ins says that the branches not chosen may still generate syntax errors, but I fail to see how mismatched types are syntax errors.

Anyway, you can get rid of the warnings when you move the arguments to the function out of the type-dependent choice. So (in pseudocode in order to make it more readable), instead of

```
choose_type_of(x, int, print_int(x), 
choose_type_of(x, char[], print_string(x), (void) 0))
```

do

```
choose_type_of(x, int, print_int, 
choose_type_of(x, char[], print_string, pass))(x)
```

That's what user2357112 suggested in a comment. I was working on a similar solution, but I had a hard time to get the default part (the `pass` above) to work. When I use `(void)`, which should then expand to `(void)(x)`, I get an error about an unmatched parenthesis.

The solution below creates a default printing function that doesn't use its arguments. It could probably be a non-existent function, so that there are problems when linking or something else that produces an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(x)                                                    \
    __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x),   \
        int), print_int,                                            \
    __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x),   \
        const char[]), print_string,                                \
    print_any))(x)


void print_int(int i) {
    printf("int: %d\n", i);
}

void print_string(const char *s) {
    printf("char[]: %s\n", s);
}

void print_any() {
    printf("unknown\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 9;
    const char str[] = "hello";

    print(n);
    print(str);

    print(1);
    print("this");

    print(3.2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(void)` didn't work because we're choosing an expression, not a sequence of tokens, and `(void)` isn't a complete expression.

Comment: @user2357112: Good point. Generating a compiler error in the default clause is probably the better approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with several methods that achieve function overloading.

One poster mentioned this

> The GNU page on the build-ins says that the branches not chosen may
>   still generate syntax errors, but I fail to see how mismatched types
>   are syntax errors.

The syntax errors they're referring to I believe are the compiler warnings you get because after preprocessing the compiler can see that the types of the arguments to some functions, even though they can never be called are wrong. The solution (which I think is quite neat) is to find a way to hide the types from the compiler. The obvious way is varargs, the less obvious way is is the current answer to the OP's question.

Caveats apply ie not all solutions are type safe and this is entirely specific to GNU...

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(x)                                                                        \
  (__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int   ), print_int   , \
   __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]), print_string, \
  (void)0))(x))

#define print1(x)                                                                          \
  __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int   ), print_int1(1,x)   , \
  __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]), print_string1(1,x), \
 (void)0))

#define print2(x)                                                                    \
  __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int   ), printer(1,x), \
  __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]), printer(2,x), \
 (void)0))

#define TYPE_ID(x) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int   ) * 1 \
                +  __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]) * 2  

#define print3(x) printer(TYPE_ID(x), x)

#define STATIC_ASSERT(COND,MSG) typedef char static_assertion_##MSG[(COND)?1:-1]

#define print4(x) \
    STATIC_ASSERT(TYPE_ID(x), __LINE__); \
    printer(TYPE_ID(x), x)

void printer(int i, ...) {
  va_list v;
  va_start(v, i); 
  switch(i) {
    case 1:{ 
             int arg = va_arg(v, int);
             printf("int: %d\n", arg);
             va_end(v);
             break;
           }
    case 2:{
             char * arg = va_arg(v, char*);
             printf("char*: %s\n", arg);
             va_end(v);
             break;
           }
    default: {
               fprintf(stderr, "Unknown type, abort\n");
               abort();
             }
  }
}

void print_int(int i) {
    printf("int: %d\n", i);
}

void print_string(char* s) {
    printf("char*: %s\n", s);
}
void print_int1(int i, ...) {
  va_list v;
  va_start(v, i);
  int arg = va_arg(v, int);
  printf("int: %d\n", arg);
  va_end(v);
}

void print_string1(int i, ...) {
  va_list v;
  va_start(v, i);
  char * arg = va_arg(v, char*);
  printf("char*: %s\n", arg);
  va_end(v);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int  var    = 1729;
  double var1 = 1729;
  //Type safe
  //print(var1);//Comple time error
  print(var);
  print("print");

  /* Following are not Type Safe */
  print1(var1);// BAD... Does nothing.
  print1(var);
  print1("print1");

  print2(var1);// BAD... Does nothing.
  print2(var);
  print2("print2");

  //print3(var1);//Evil... Runtime error
  print3(var);
  print3("print3");

  //Type Safe
  //print4(var1);//Comple time error
  print4(var);
  print4("print4");
  return 0;
}
```

Source is on github...

https://github.com/harryjackson/doc/blob/master/c/overload_c_functions.c

The switch method with multiple arguments can be found here...

http://locklessinc.com/articles/overloading/

The whole

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be suppressed by doing some type casting in the `#define` section, but I feel like this probably is not the best or even a good solution at all...

Change the function calls in the `#define` section to this:

```
print_string((char*)x)
print_int((int)x)
```

I really hope someone comes up with a better solution though, because this just feels wrong...

Comment: I just came up with the same idea, it however, will only give you a different warning: `-Wpointer-to-int-cast`.

Comment: I compiled it with `gcc -Wall` and it gets rid of the warnings.  Compiling with `g++` however will completely fail with numerous errors.

Comment: It fails in C++ because neither of the builtins are available in C++, as per gcc's documentation.