# Function overloading in C using GCC - functions with mutiple arguments

Tags: c, gcc, c99, overloading, preprocessor-directive

In a previous question I found a way to overload functions in C99 when each function only took a single argument.  See the answers in: [Function overloading in C using GCC - compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506988/function-overloading-in-c-compiler-warnings) for details.

Now that I've found a way to do it with single argument functions I'm wondering how this can be done for functions that take multiple arguments.  I assume it will have something to do with `__VA_ARGS__` and using `...` but I can't seem to find anything that works or even wants to compile.

---

This will work for a print that takes 2 arguments:

```
#define print(x, y)                                                            \
__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), int) &&          \
                      __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(y), int), print_int, \
(void)0)(x, y)
```

But if I also want another version that takes one argument I can't redefine it.  Adding this will give me an error saying `print` is redefined:

```
#define print(x)                                                                     \
__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), char[]), print_string, \
(void)0)(x)
```

---

How can I overload print so it will work with 2 integers as an input or with a character array?

example usage:

```
print(1, 2);
print("this");
```

Or even better... how can I make it work with any combination of types or any number of arguments?

**Also remember, since this is C99 the _Generic keyword is not available.**

Comment: A slight correction: You found a way to emulate function overloads using GCC ***extensions***. This is most definitely not part of the C99 standard.

Comment: Horrible solution to me.. BTW why, if overloading is mandatory, don't you switch to g++?

Comment: I never said this was part of the c99 standard, in fact I specified that I was using GCC in the linked question.  Plus this is not a question about why this should or should not be done, but how.  It should be done simply because it can be done.

Comment: A clear statement: This is a terrible hack, **do not**!. In companies with good coding styles (even iff they allow extension), you will get into real trouble with that.

Comment: "I never said this was part of the c99 standard" - Well, you tagged the question `C` and `C99`, but not with the most relevant tag: `gcc`. And the title is also missleading.

Comment: @Olaf, Look at the tags. It is tagged gcc.  And just because the title doesn't clearly state that does not make it misleading.

Comment: Also I am aware that this is a hack and is probably terrible practice.  That is not part of the question.  I simply wish to know if it CAN be done.   Regardless of whether this should be used or not, it is still useful knowledge to have.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the gcc tag. Re. bad practice: This site is consulted by beginners a lot. Chances are good they adopt this bad practice. Thus at least a warning in the comments is well rectified.

Comment: This will go WAYYY over a beginners head... so I find that unlikely.  But I agree, a warning in the comments is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with GCC's extensions and with an overdose of preprocessor tricks. The commenters have already made their opinion clear: C is rather explicit and has a one-to-one relationship with the symbols produced. If you want function overloading and type inspection, use one of the many languages that provide them.

Baroque macro solutions tend to be toys rather than code that's suitable for production, but it's still an interesting exercise to push the envelope. Safety helemts on, though, and be aware that:

- ... the solution isn't portable, because the core gimmick of choosing arguments via types is already GCC specific.
- ... the solution is build on macros. Finding syntax errors in macros is difficult, because the error messages refer to expanded code that the user doesn't see.
- ... the solution pollutes the namespace with many macro names. If you really want to use this solution, prefix all your macros (except the most visible ones) consistenty as to minimize the danger of symbol collision.

That out of the way, let's implement a function `put` that writes its arguments to `stdin` according to its type:

```
const char *name = "Fred";
double C = 12.5;

put(1, " ", 2);                         // 1 2
put("Hello, I'm ", name, "!");          // Hello, I'm Fred!
put(C, " Celsius");                     // 12.5 Celsius
put(C * 1.8 + 32.0, " Fahrenheit");     // 54.5 Fahrenheit
```

For the sake of simplicity, the solution accepts only up to three arguments of either `int`, `const char *` or `double`, but the maximum number of arguments is extensible.

The solution consists of these parts:

#### Variadic constant-type macros

Say you want to have a function that sums all arguments. The number of arguments may vary, but all arguments are of type `double`. If they are not of type `double`, they should be promoted to `double`.

Variadic functions aren't a good solution, because they will pass the arguments to the function per individual type. trying to `sum(1, 2, 3)` as `double` will have disastrous results.

Instead, you can use compound literals to create an array of `double`s on the fly. Use the `sizeof` mechanism to get the length of the array. (The arguments may have side effects, because the array inside the `sizeof` isn't evaluated, only its size is determined.)

```
#define sum(...) sum_impl(sizeof((double[]){__VA_ARGS__})/ \
                 sizeof(double), (double[]){__VA_ARGS__})

double sum_impl(size_t n, double x[])
{
    double s = 0.0;

    while (n--) s += x[n];
    return s;
}
```

This will yield `6.0` for `sum(1, 2, 3)` in a calculation performed on `double`s.

#### Variant type

You want all arguments to be of the same type, but this type should be able to represent all supported types of your function. The C way to create a variant is to use a tagged union, a `union` inside a `struct`:

```
typedef struct var_t var_t;

struct var_t {
    int type;
    union {
        int i;
        double f;
        const char *s;
    } data;
};
```

The type could be an enumeration. I use charcter constants according the to `printf` formats here.

The variant of an expression is determined with a macro `VAR`, which is essentially the gcc specific you have posted above:

```
#define CHOOSE __builtin_choose_expr
#define IFTYPE(X, T) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(X), T)

#define VAR(X)                                          \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, int),          make_var_i,         \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, const char[]), make_var_s,         \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, const char *), make_var_s,         \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, double),       make_var_f,         \
                                    make_var_0))))(X)
```

The macro invokes any of the `make_var` functions. These functions must be defined for each valid type:

```
var_t make_var_i(int X)         { var_t v = {'i', {.i = X}}; return v; }
var_t make_var_s(const char *X) { var_t v = {'s', {.s = X}}; return v; }
var_t make_var_f(double X)      { var_t v = {'f', {.f = X}}; return v; }
var_t make_var_0()              { var_t v = {'#'}; return v; }
```

Incorporating the `X` into the type-dependent expression doesn't work, as you have already found out. Neither can you use compound literals with designated initialisers here, probably for the same reasons. (I've said that error checking with macros is hard, haven't I?)

This is the only GCC specific part; it could also be achieved with C11's `_Generic`.

#### Applying the macro to all arguments of a function

You must apply the `VAR` macro to all arguments of your variadic `put` macro. You cannot process the head of the variadic arguments until you get an empty list, because you cannot expand macros recursively, but you can use a trick that counts the arguments to the macro and then expand to a macro that takes that many arguments:

```
#define PUT1(_1)            put_impl(1, (var_t[]){VAR(_1)})
#define PUT2(_1, _2)        put_impl(2, (var_t[]){VAR(_1), VAR(_2)})
#define PUT3(_1, _2, _3)    put_impl(3, (var_t[]){VAR(_1), VAR(_2), VAR(_3)})

#define SELECT_N(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N

#define put(...) SELECT_N(__VA_ARGS__, PUT3, PUT2, PUT1)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Now `put` takes 1, 2 or 3 arguments. If you provide more than 3, you get an obscure error message that doesn't have anything to do with not providing too many arguments.

The code above will not accept an empty argument list. With the GCC entension `, ##__VA_ARGS`, which will write a comma only if the variadicargument list isn't empty, you can extend this to:

```
#define PUT0()              put_impl(0, NULL)
#define PUT1(_1)            put_impl(1, (var_t[]){VAR(_1)})
#define PUT2(_1, _2)        put_impl(2, (var_t[]){VAR(_1), VAR(_2)})
#define PUT3(_1, _2, _3)    put_impl(3, (var_t[]){VAR(_1), VAR(_2), VAR(_3)})

#define SELECT_N(X, _1, _2, _3, N, ...) N

#define put(...) SELECT_N(X, ##__VA_ARGS__, PUT3, PUT2, PUT1,PUT0)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

You can extend this solution to arbitrarily many arguments if you like.

#### The implementation

The above macro invokes the function `put_impl`, which is the implementation of how to print an array of `n` variants. After all the tricks above, the functions is rather straightforward:

```
void put_impl(size_t n, const var_t var[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        switch(var[i].type) {
        case 'i':   printf("%i", var[i].data.i); break;
        case 'f':   printf("%g", var[i].data.f); break;
        case 's':   printf("%s", var[i].data.s); break;
        case '#':   printf("[undef]"); break;
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

#### Putting it all together

The following program uses the method described above to print some rather silly stuff. It is not portable, but runs if compiled with `gcc -std=gnu99`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHOOSE __builtin_choose_expr
#define IFTYPE(X, T) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(X), T)

#define VAR(X)                                          \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, int),          make_var_i,         \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, const char[]), make_var_s,         \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, const char *), make_var_s,         \
    CHOOSE(IFTYPE(X, double),       make_var_f,         \
                                    make_var_0))))(X)

#define PUT0()              put_impl(0, NULL)
#define PUT1(_1)            put_impl(1, (var_t[]){VAR(_1)})
#define PUT2(_1, _2)        put_impl(2, (var_t[]){VAR(_1), VAR(_2)})
#define PUT3(_1, _2, _3)    put_impl(3, (var_t[]){VAR(_1), VAR(_2), VAR(_3)})

#define SELECT_N(X, _1, _2, _3, N, ...) N

#define put(...) SELECT_N(X, ##__VA_ARGS__, PUT3, PUT2, PUT1,PUT0)(__VA_ARGS__)

typedef struct var_t var_t;

struct var_t {
    int type;
    union {
        int i;
        double f;
        const char *s;
    } data;
};

var_t make_var_i(int X)         { var_t v = {'i', {.i = X}}; return v; }
var_t make_var_s(const char *X) { var_t v = {'s', {.s = X}}; return v; }
var_t make_var_f(double X)      { var_t v = {'f', {.f = X}}; return v; }
var_t make_var_0()              { var_t v = {'#'}; return v; }

void put_impl(size_t n, const var_t var[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        switch(var[i].type) {
        case 'i':   printf("%i", var[i].data.i); break;
        case 'f':   printf("%g", var[i].data.f); break;
        case 's':   printf("%s", var[i].data.s); break;
        case '#':   printf("[undef]"); break;
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
    const char *name = "Fred";
    double C = 12.5;

    put(1, " ", 2);
    put("Hello, I'm ", name, "!");
    put();
    put(C, " Celsius");
    put(C * 1.8 + 32.0, " Fahrenheit");

    return 0;
}
```

You can go crazy on the types and number of arguments you want to support, but keep inn mind that the bigger your jungle of macros gets, the harder it will be to maintain and to debug.

Comment: This is incredibly informative! It may take me a while to understand but this is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: How can I make this recognize an overload that takes no arguments? For example: `put();`

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I've added support for empty argument lists via GCC's `, ##__VA_ARGS__` syntax, which will put a cmma before the variadic arguments if they are not empty.

Comment: I understand the good solid reasons why exportable functions cannot support overloading.  Are there any semantic reasons why C could not support overloading of `static` and `static inline` functions, given that compilers are not expected to give a static function any particular link-time name (and in many cases have to mangle names to avoid link-time errors if static functions declared in different compilation units have the same name).

Comment: @supercat: Static functions could probaby be overloaded, yes, but overloaded functions make more sense as a versatile interface to other objects and libraries, where symbol names must be exported.

Comment: @MOehm: If a compiler allows static and static inline functions to be overloaded, then a header file which says e.g. `overload static inline void print(int x) { print_int(x); } overload static inline void print(float x) { print_float(x); }` etc. can achieve all the semantic benefits of overloading without name mangling.

Comment: @supercat: At the cost of including the implementation as `static` functions in each object file. I also don't see why you are discussing this with me. I don't make the C language, I just use it.

Comment: @MOehm: Static inline functions don't generally appear in the object file--functions like the above would typically generate the same code as if `print_int`, etc. had been called directly.  I was just curious if you saw any problem with that "compromise" approach since I would think it should offer all the semantic benefits of overloading but without any name-mangling confusion and without making functions unavailable to compilers that can't support overloading (since they could call the explicitly-named `print_int`, etc.)

Comment: In this case, where the overloaded functions are one-liners, they will probably be inlined. (I never use the `inline` keyword and try to make as many function as possible `static`. I haven't done that here, because the focus was on the macros. I also guess that the question is about an external interface.) This solution delegates the name-mangling to macro wrappers. Why should a C compiler allow the non-standard overloading of static functions as special case?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is in no way generic, but it will get the job done for the very specific case asked in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(...) \
        __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)), int), print_int, print_string)\
(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FIRST(A, ...) A

void print_int(int i, int j) {
    printf("int: %d %d\n", i, j);
}

void print_string(char* s) {
    printf("char*: %s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    print(1, 2);
    print("this");

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can find a more generalized solution that will work consistently when new overloads are added that would be greatly appreciated.