# avr-gcc: warning: 'overloadable' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I have a function, i need to overload, but compiler ignoring in and gives me an error later:

```cpp
warning: 'overloadable' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
[build]    11 | Vec3 multiply(Vec3 a, double b) __attribute__((overloadable));
[build]       | ^~~~
```

```
error: conflicting types for 'multiply'
[build]    11 | Vec2 multiply(Vec2 a, double b);
[build]       |      ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: If you need overloading  write in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC does not support `__attribute__((overloadable))`, it's Clang's extension. C does not have function overloading, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864513/gcc-allow-overloaded-functions-in-c99) for workarounds via macros.